# how to write a json file with CRLF endline using WRITE-JSON() function in progress 4GL/openedge

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

```
DATASET mydataset:WRITE-JSON("file",filename,YES,"utf-8",NO)
```

I writed code like this , but got a file with LF endline.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really important (it should not), you will have to write the JSON Object into a Longchar variable and change the line ending with the replace function.